# Как задать URL для конкретного метода контроллера в ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, rest, маршрутизация, asp.net-core-mvc

Пишу API в рамках сервиса. Есть такой контроллер с одним POST-методом `Send`:

```
[Route("api/fens")]
[ApiController]
public class FeatureEnvironmentController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("api/fens/Send")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public IActionResult Send([FromBody] FeatureEnvironmentIncomingContract featureEnvironmentIncomingContract)
    { 
        var featureEnvironmentManager = new FeatureEnvironmentManager();

        try
        {
            var featureEnvironment = featureEnvironmentManager.CreateFeatureEnvironment(
                featureEnvironmentIncomingContract.Name,
                featureEnvironmentIncomingContract.UserLogin,
                featureEnvironmentIncomingContract.LoginPageUrl);

            featureEnvironmentManager.Send(featureEnvironment);

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }
    }
}
```

Пытаюсь через атрибут "Route" назначить контроллеру путь, по которому до него можно достучаться. При запуске и попытке пройти на url `{root:portNum}/api/fens/Send` возвращается статус 404.

В Configure-методе есть строка, подключающая MVC, но не специфицирующая шаблоны для рутов:

```
app.UseMvc();
```

Как правильно назначить путь для метода контроллера? В первый раз работаю с ASP.NET Core

Comment: А зачем вы на него `Route` вешаете? Просто в атрибут `HttpPost` добавьте `[HttpPost("send")]`. А атрибут `Route` уберите с метода.

Comment: `При запуске и попытке пройти на url {root:portNum}/api/fens/Send` попытка пройти по URL - это GET запрос, а у вас метод работает только для POST звпроса.

Comment: @ヒミコ спасибо, помогло

Comment: @tym32167 да, не совсем правильно выразился.

Comment: @ヒミコ желаете оформить ответ на вопрос?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для того что бы определить направление метода для вызова, необходимо устанавливать в атрибут `Http[Post/Get/Put/...]` именование маршрута, а точнее путь к нему.

Для примера:

```
[Route("api/fens")]
[ApiController]
public class FeatureEnvironmentController : ControllerBase
{
    // e.g: {root:portNum}/api/fens/[S/s]end
    [HttpPost("Send")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public IActionResult Send([FromBody] FeatureEnvironmentIncomingContract featureEnvironmentIncomingContract)
    { 
        var featureEnvironmentManager = new FeatureEnvironmentManager();

        try
        {
            var featureEnvironment = featureEnvironmentManager.CreateFeatureEnvironment(
                featureEnvironmentIncomingContract.Name,
                featureEnvironmentIncomingContract.UserLogin,
                featureEnvironmentIncomingContract.LoginPageUrl);

            featureEnvironmentManager.Send(featureEnvironment);

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            return new StatusCodeResult(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
        }
    }
}
```

Обратите внимание на строку `[HttpPost("Send")]`, это говорит о том что при отправке запроса к адресу `{root:portNum}/api/fens/[S/s]end`, будет вызван именно этот метод. так же таких методов может быть несколько, но они могут принимать разные параметры, при этом, вам необходимо будет настроить приоритет подбора метода.